# Live Search in textentries [JS ONLY]

Tags: javascript, search, filter, livesearch

I need your help in writing a JavaScript. What it needs to do is:

- Filter (by `display: block` and `display: none`) my textentries (div containers with each textentries) when I type a word (or a part of that) contained in my textentries. Empty searchbox should show all entries.

I know I need to use here RegEx and InnerHTML. Does anybody know how to write something like that? I cannot use anything but handwritten JavaScript (no  ready-made solution and NO JQuery).

My HTML:

`<article id="content">
    <form action="#" id="search">
        <input type="search" id="filterTxt" placeholder="Filter entries"/>
        <input type="button" class="startSearch" value="Search"></form>
            <div id="entry1">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            </div>
            <div id="entry2">
                <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo</p>
            </div>
            <div id="entry3">
                <p>Stet clita kasd gubergren</p>
            </div>
</article>`

When I type in the searchbox a word (or a part of it) contained in `div#entry1`, I want `div#entry2` and `div#entry3` to disappear by `display: none`.

Comment: Hey @Melisa something like that?
http://vdw.github.io/HideSeek/
Enjoy!

Comment: Please provide a minimal code(HTML atleast) and see if [jQuery's autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) is helpful.

Comment: Could you provide html with comments?
I'm sure that answer is quiet simple but I still can't understand what exactly you need.

Comment: i edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution:

```
var input = document.getElementById("filterTxt");
var searchBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("startSearch")[0];
var entries = document.getElementsByClassName("entry"); // don't forget to add class 'entry' to your divs

searchBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var val = input.value;
    for (var i=0, l=entries.length; i<l; i++) {
        var entryText = entries[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;
        if (entryText.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1) entries[i].style.display = "block"; // add toLowerCase method to ignore case
        else entries[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}, false)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2w9kpgft/1/

You also can add "input" listener to your text input element to filter your results on input.

http://jsfiddle.net/2w9kpgft/2/

Comment: yeah, thats what i need but it doesnt work in my html code, only in jsfiddle but i'll try to fix it

Comment: I put the same code in my html file but nothing happens and there is an error `input is null`

Comment: Try to wrap it in window.onload function. http://jsfiddle.net/2w9kpgft/8/ It will work in your page but not in jsfiddle. or you can add this code in <script type="text/javascript"></script> tag in the end of your body tag

Comment: woah okay, it works! now i only need a reset button, so i can clear the searchbox and have all my entries displayed again... thank you very much, i though it needs much more code than that

Comment: Here are some fixes in code and a 'reset' button http://jsfiddle.net/2w9kpgft/11/

Comment: thats what i wanted, thank you very much! it works perfectly